# start-all.sh error while installing hadoop on ubuntu 12.04lts

Tags: hadoop, failed-installation

I have been referring to [this link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) for **hadoop-1.1.1 installation**.

All my files and permissions have been set according to this link.
But I am getting this error.Please help.

> hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/start-all.sh mkdir: cannot create
>   directory `/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs': Permission denied
>   chown: cannot access`/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs': No such file
>   or directory starting namenode, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-ubuntu.out
>   /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136:
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-ubuntu.out:
>   No such file or directory head: cannot open
>   `/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-ubuntu.out'
>   for reading: No such file or directory localhost: mkdir: cannot create
>   directory`/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs': Permission denied
>   localhost: chown: cannot access `/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs':
>   No such file or directory localhost: starting datanode, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-ubuntu.out
>   localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136:
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-ubuntu.out:
>   No such file or directory localhost: head: cannot open`
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-ubuntu.out'
>   for reading: No such file or directory localhost: mkdir: cannot create
>   directory `/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs': Permission denied
>   localhost: chown: cannot access`/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs':
>   No such file or directory localhost: starting secondarynamenode,
>   logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-ubuntu.out
>   localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136:
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-ubuntu.out:
>   No such file or directory localhost: head: cannot open
>   `/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-ubuntu.out'
>   for reading: No such file or directory mkdir: cannot create directory`
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs': Permission denied chown: cannot
>   access `/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs': No such file or directory
>   starting jobtracker, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-ubuntu.out
>   /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136:
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-ubuntu.out:
>   No such file or directory head: cannot open`
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-ubuntu.out'
>   for reading: No such file or directory localhost: mkdir: cannot create
>   directory `/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs': Permission denied
>   localhost: chown: cannot access`/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs':
>   No such file or directory localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-ubuntu.out
>   localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136:
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-ubuntu.out:
>   No such file or directory localhost: head: cannot open
>   `/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-ubuntu.out'
>   for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you formatted the namenode before doing "bin/start-all.sh". Looks like your namenode is not formatted properly.

Comment: Furthermore please check the permissions to `/usr/local/hadoop/log/`. Can you access this directory as `hduser`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672672/error-while-starting-hadoop-cluster

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests you're having a permission problem.
You need to give hduser proper permissions. Try:

```
sudo chown -R hduser /usr/local/hadoop/
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to change the permission of the hadoop directory

> sudo chmod 750 /app/hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Below are 2 very helpful suggestions:

1. It is good to check whether HADOOP_HOME and JAVA_HOME is set in
   .bashrc file. Sometimes, not setting up these environment variables
   may also cause error while starting the hadoop cluster.
2. It is also useful to debug the error by going through the log files generated in /usr/local/hadoop/logs directory.